# How to change location, rotation, scale and dimensions of more objects at the same time?

Tags: animation, objects, transforms, scale

I'm trying to change the **location, rotation, scale and dimensions** of **many objects at the same time**. It's about 80 planes mapped with different textures. I've imported these planes using the addon "**image sequence as planes**". After having selected every plane,I see that I can change the value of **only one plane**. Is there another way to do this ?

[image: selected objects in blender]

Comment: It really depends on what you mean precisely, you could parent them all to the same object and transform the object, but will it satisfy your need?

Comment: yes if it works. I've just tried. I've selected all the planes together and then I have parented them to an empty object. After this I have changed the value of the Y axis on the empty object to 0. When I click on the planes I see that they haven't changed the y value to 0

Comment: maybe join them all with ctrl J, make your transforms, the separate by loose parts? I don't know, maybe you should explain more precisely what's the situation and what you're trying to do, I think it lacks precisions...

Comment: or maybe unparent your object from your empty (alt P) with the keep transform option?

Comment: only joining the planes with ctrl J and so on worked.

Comment: I've just realized that in my specific situation the method above did not work...here -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1r4Ltv-3qb2ardxfpvBDiuELw68IPc12Q you can see what's the situation before to join all the planes in one only object,and here --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tYrIlAu4uFXLLbgrHHwLswS1a0yP9b7E you can see what's happened after...

Comment: if your goal is to display a series of images, don't you want to create one unique object and give it an Image Texture node > Image Sequence mode (instead of Single Image)?

Comment: If you have any issues using Loom, please report that here: [https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom/issues](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom/issues) preferably along with your os, blender version etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly and you just need to set the same value for multiple objects at once, there is simple trick for this purpose:

1. Select all the objects
2. **Click the input field while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>**
3. Enter the value

[image]

In the default behaviour, new value is set only for the *active* object (the last selected one).

Comment: thanks for the trick, you talk about the default behavior, so what's the non-default you're using? because when I try your method, the new value is set only to the active object, the other objects also move but not to the entered value

Comment: it seems that it works good...

Comment: @moonboots - do you hold Alt while clicking into input field?

Comment: yes, maybe it's my settings, I don't know, I'll try to find out, thanks  ;)

Comment: FYI, I am using Blender 2.79, maybe it doesn't work in some earlier versions.