# How can I change the X, Y or Z transform values of all a curve's control points at the same time?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, transforms

I'm trying to change the *X*, *Y* or *Z* values of all a curve's control points at the same time (while I'm in *Edit mode*). What I do is to select all the curve vertex points and then on the *X*, *Y* or *Z* fields on the *Transform / Median* tab I change the value. When I keep selected *all* the points at the same time the value is correctly changed, but when I select *each* control point, I see that the old value is still there.

Let's take this post :

[How to change location, rotation, scale and dimensions of more objects at the same time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120995/how-to-change-location-rotation-scale-and-dimensions-of-more-objects-at-the-sa)

The user **Jan Kadeřábek** said to:

> 1. Select all the objects
> 2. Click the input field while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>
> 3. Enter the value

I thought that it could also work in this situation, but it does not. Maybe because it was in *Object mode*, instead now I'm in *Edit mode*?

Answer (score 2):

A common trick to align things is to scale to zero on an axis.

- Select multiple control points
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to align them on the x axis
- Change the x axis value to the desired value